# How To Achieve "Cache-Control: public, max-age=600" using AspNetCacheProfile in WCF

Tags: wcf, outputcache, cache-control

I'm in the middle of applying caching to our enterprise API. I'm trying to achieve a Cache-Control of type "**public**, max-age=600" for compatibility with our Load Balancer which supports Reverse Proxy Caching.

However, I can only get WCF to output "**private**, max-age=600", which isn't right for the Reverse Proxy Caching.

I have the following profile set to location:Server (as I need ASP application level caching) but I have also tried all the other locations but none will give me Public.

```
<caching>
  <outputCache enableOutputCache="true"/>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="CacheDefault" duration="600" varyByParam="none" location="Any" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

Im using standard WCF like this, nothing fancy:

```
    [AspNetCacheProfile("CacheDefault")]
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetData/{value}")]
    string GetData(string value);
```

I've even started a brand new WCF service project just to remove any confounding variables that may be in my current production code, but it still outputs private.

**P.S.** I should probably make it clear that I'm not looking to override the WebOperationContext.current.outgoingresponse.headers manually. I'm after a quick win with configuring the AspNetCacheProfile.

Any help would be great!

Many thanks!

Oliver

Answer (score 0):

I came across different caching techniques. I posted some of those which i found to be useful here
http://itswadesh.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/caching-in-asp-net/

Comment: Sorry but that's not appropriate for this scenario. Many thanks, Oliver